# If a serve is measured at 185 km/h, how many seconds does it take for the tennis ball to travel the length of the court?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the length of the court in meters? 23.8 m The court is 78ft long. How many seconds will it take the tennis ball to travel 78ft or 23.8m? The ball travels at 185km/h and at 168.6ft/sec.

Comment: 1) The ball slows down considerably during its flight
2) The serving area is 21 feet long from the net, total = 39 + 31 = 60 feet, not 78 feet.
3) topspin changes the flight path significantly

Answer (score 4):

speed (v)   = distance (d) / Time(s) therefor 
**Time (s)    = Distance (d)/ Speed (v)**
            = 78 / 168.6
            = 0.46 Sec

Comment: The serve would be out of bounds because in $0.46s$ the ball would only have dropped
$$\frac{1}{2}9.8\frac{m}{s^2}(0.46s)^2\approx 1.03m$$
If the ball was in bounds you would have to aim it downwards and recompute the time with the dot product (but would it clear the net?). +1 though